# Make the preprocessing of a dfm in the input column without the need to create the dfm

Tags: r, quanteda

Having a dataframe like this

```
dataf <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4), text = c("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s","Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now","There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour","a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum",""))
```

It is possible to make a text analysis preprocessing using the construction of dfm

```
myDfm <- myCorpus %>%
     tokens(remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE)  %>%
     tokens_remove(pattern = c(stopwords(source = "smart"), mystopwords))  %>% tokens_wordstem() %>% 
     dfm(verbose = FALSE) %>% dfm_trim(min_docfreq = 3, min_termfreq = 5)
```

Is there any alternative option to remover the stopwords stopwords(source = "smart"), make the wordstem and make the trim min_docfreq = 3, min_termfreq = 5 in the text column without need to create the dfm?

Comment: What form of output do you want? For `dataf$text` as a character vector but without stopwords, with the words stemmed, and with the items trimmed according to your trim criteria?  (Also...why?)

Comment: @KenBenoit yes I want the input option of data data frame. If it helps you to understand the structure. I want this because I want to use it as an example in order to create a dtm and a vocubulary with is used to calculate different coherence metrics from a topic model like here https://towardsdatascience.com/beginners-guide-to-lda-topic-modelling-with-r-e57a5a8e7a25

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll answer this based on the question plus comment, since it seems you need a dgCMatrix class for what you want to do.  (This is what is returned by `textmineR::CreateDtm()`.)  Fortunately, a **quanteda** dfm is a special type of dgCMatrix already.  So it would probably work as is, but if you want, it's also easy to convert -- just use `as()`.

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 3.0.0
## Unicode version: 10.0
## ICU version: 61.1
## Parallel computing: 12 of 12 threads used.
## See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.
data(nih_sample, package = "textmineR")

dfmat <- nih_sample %>%
  corpus(text_field = "ABSTRACT_TEXT", docid_field = "APPLICATION_ID") %>%
  tokens() %>%
  tokens_ngrams(n = 1:2) %>%
  dfm()
dtm2 <- as(dfmat, "dgCMatrix")
```

Now, `dtm2` should work same as `dtm` as in the blog post.  (The features/columns are in a different order, but that should not matter for a matrix that will be input to a topic model.)  And: it's a WHOLE lot cleaner process.

Feel free here to insert additional `tokens()` options or `dfm_trim()` etc as you need from **quanteda**.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have in quanteda any option to calculate the coherence metric in topic modeling?

Comment: No, quanteda does not have topic model functions as part of the core package. But's it's a much better way to prepare your textual data matrix than other packages.